# как отправить дополнительное поле на почту при заказе woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email

с корзины в checkout передаю доп поле present:

```
<form method="post" action="https://domen.ru/checkout/" id="form-present">
    <input type="hidden" name="present" id="present1">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" class="present-sub" value="Оформить заказ">
  </form>
```

Оно передается и выводится на странице оформления заказа (checkout), как с checkout передать это поле в письмо при клике по кнопке оформить заказ?

Comment: В WC есть и доп поля и можно добавить сколько хочешь других. Это делается функциями WC или с пом. плагинов.

Comment: Зачем выкидывать??

Comment: Потому что "это" не имеет никакого отношения к ВП.

Comment: Ваш ответ не имеет никакого отношения к моему вопросу тогда уж

Comment: нечитатель.. :( Или не пониматель. Бывает. (о, блин, кто-то отредактил мой вчерашний коммент. Вот что за фигня?!)

Comment: завязывай балоболить  )