# Как добавить текстовое поле в письмо woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

передаю скрытое поле ajax'ом в functions.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       var present2 = jQuery("#present2").val();
       jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
        action : "ajax_present",
        "present2" : present2
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data)
        }
      });  
    });
</script>
```

functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_present', 'ajax_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_present', 'ajax_form' );

function ajax_form(){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'display_applied_present', 10, 4 );
            function display_applied_present( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

                    $present_code = $_POST['present2'];
                    echo '+Подарок' .$present_code;
            };
}
```

в письме почему то ничего не приходит, подскажите пожалуйста решение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как отправить дополнительное поле на почту при заказе woocommerce](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166934/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-woocommerce)

Comment: А почему указано, что это дубликат [этой темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166934/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-woocommerce), но там же должно быть решение, а там нет никаких ответов. Если кто-то уже решил задачу, то дайте пожалуйста ответ.